# (CRON) error (grandchild #26321 failed with exit status 127)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, rvm, passenger

I am using [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) my schedule.rb content is

> every 2.minutes do   runner
>   "Refinery::Page.update_publishing_date_to_list_in_menu" end

I get this by crontab -l

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /home/harssh/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspacwinbox/wineboxnew/config/schedule.rb

0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58
* * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/harssh/Documents/Aptana\ Studio\ 3\ Workspacwinbox/wineboxnew && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake page:publish --silent'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /home/harssh/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspacwinbox/wineboxnew/config/schedule.rb
```

This runs well on my ubuntu 10.10

But I get `(CRON) error (grandchild #26321 failed with exit status 127)` on my debian server 
where I am using apache and passenger with rvm using Ruby 1.9.3

If I use script in terminal in debian it also runs properly but automated cron task gives error

Comment: anything in a /log/cron.log?

Comment: LOL and it could be just `*/2` ... the `127` problem is missing command - most likely is a `PATH` issue ...

Comment: tile of this page is content of log file Vadim

Comment: yes mpapis is assumed that 127 is path error I gave all possible paths and set environment but it always gives 127 error

Comment: I would like to know if there a specific way to give path which I may be missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also faced same problem, Finally I resolved this issue.

**Problem 1:** Ruby path in script/runner file

ruby path in script/runner file:

#!**/usr/local/bin/ruby**

You can replace **(/usr/local/bin/ruby**) with your machine ruby path. You can check ruby path with the following command in your machine:

**which ruby**

**Problem 2:** I think your runner don't have execution permission.

You can set execution permission to runner file the following way:

Ruby project path/script> chmod +x ruuner